# Unable to build apk in react native expo

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

While trying to build an apk from a react native project using below command, am getting below error.

eas build -p android

[image]

I have tried to replace open the image in paint and again saved it so that image wont be corrupted.

Below is my folder strucutre for that project.

[image]

Kindly help. Thanks

Comment: Pls find the project here
https://github.com/mendismenon/md_reactnative

Answer (score 0):

try building it local

```
    eas build --platform android --local
eas build --platform ios --local
```